# Cleaning an IGLOO Freestanding Ice Maker water box

Tags: cleaning, ice-maker

An [IGLOO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igloo_Products_Corporation) Freestanding Ice Maker (Model # ICE102C-SILVER) [image: Freestanding Ice Maker] has water box [image: water box] which the instruction state should be cleaned. The inside of the box is not accessible in either the empty nor the fill position.

How does one get at it or remove it for cleaning?

Comment: Call igloo and ask?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be answerable with a call to the company or a visit to their web site.

Answer (score 0):

I would empty the contents, then using a mild detergent (I prefer dishwashing detergent) and gently clean the best you can and then rinse with a damp cloth. Finally wipe dry. This is not perfect but much better then disassembling the unit to clean it.